# Duhamel's formula

Tags: lie-groups, ho.history-overview

Formula (12) in the paper

- Bauer, M., Chetrite, R., Ebrahimi-Fard, K., & Patras, F. (2013).
  Time-ordering and a generalized Magnus expansion. Letters in
  Mathematical Physics, 103(3), 331-350.

expresses the derivative of an exponential of a parameter-dependent Lie algebra element. The authors call it 'Duhamel's formula', without giving a reference.

Where and in which context did Duhamel prove this formula? (I know the formula as Kubo's formula, from his work in statistical mechanics.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Duhamel's formula for the derivative of the exponent of a matrix refers to [Jean-Marie-Constant Duhamel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Marie_Duhamel), who described it in [Eléments de calcul infinitésimal](http://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb3037024) (volume 2, 1856; page 36) as a method to obtain solutions to inhomogeneous linear differential equations in terms of the solution to the homogenous equation.
In the context of Lie groups the [formula for the derivative of the exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map) is attributed to Schur (1891).

A modern proof is in these [notes.](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m428/duhamel.pdf) or alternatively [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/webpage/MatrixExpLog.pdf) (theorem 3). A formal proof is given by
\begin{align}
  \frac{d}{dt}e^{A(t)}
    &= \lim_{N \to \infty}\frac{d}{dt}\left(1 + \frac{A(t)}{N}\right)^N\\
    &= \frac{1}{N}\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^N\left(1 + \frac{A(t)}{N}\right)^{k-1}A'(t)\left(1 + \frac{A(t)}{N}\right)^{N-k}~\\
&=\int_0^1 e^{sA(t)}A'(t)e^{(1-s)A(t)}\,ds.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks!  And, just to have names for future readers, in case of linkrot:  "these notes" is [Feldman - Duhamel's formula](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m428/duhamel.pdf), and "here" is [Haber - Notes on the matrix exponential and logarithm](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/webpage/MatrixExpLog.pdf).